# Unity WebGL how to make it run properly in background

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine, browser, throttling, unity-webgl

I need full FixedUpdate calls (50 times a second) in background. How to achieve that?

Unity WebGL almost stops Update(and FixedUpdate) calls while in background. "Run In Background" is checked, When the user just clicks "New Tab" or switches tab for a second or minimizes the window, the game is working barely 1 call in every second. Which ends up as a massive lag for other players. (Multiplayer game. In background it sends barely 1 packet in every second)

Some people claim that it's up to Chrome or Firefox and throttling. But this is not true.(or there are ways to disable throttling?) Because there are P2P multiplayer browser games working properly in background. You can check Haxball for example. It does not skip packets when you minimize or switch tab.